# Runtime error: Get full Program name

Tags: visual-c++

When I run a program I get the runtime error below.  However the program file cannot be determined because I cannot view the full program file:

[image: Runtime error]

How do I get the full program file? Is there a log that stores this information?  I tried to use Event view but could not find the information.

Comment: [*may be a stupid question*] - isn't it a program that you are trying to run? Don't you know its name?

Comment: Good point, and this may be the answer however the program calls a number of other processors and I thought that the Program name above could be one of these and that would be useful information.

Comment: I would first try to run DebugView tool (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx) to see if there is some helpful output there.